# Url Blocking SMF Mod (mine) JQuery: .val() doesn't work fine

Tags: php, jquery, input

Well, I have this code:

```
//Url-Block

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function logged_in() {
  return $(\'#userStatus\').val() == \'User\' ? true : false;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(!logged_in()) {
    $("#url-lock").html("<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">[Sólo los usuarios pueden ver este contenido. <a href="' . $scripturl . '?action=register">Regístrate</a> o <a href="' . $scripturl . '?action=login">loguéate</a> para ver dicho contenido.]</span>").removeAttr("href").wrap("<strong></strong>");
  }
});
</script>';
```

That makes that the guests can't see any link that have [url-lock] bbc tag... But idk why it doesn't work...

```
#url-lock works well...
#userStatus too...
```

So.. Jquery is bad coded, that can I do? I have never programmed in Jquery ;(

The error is here:

```
    function logged_in() {
  return $(\'#userStatus\').val() == \'User\' ? true : false;
}
```

Idk, how to do that it works... :/

Sorry, and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function logged_in() {
   return $('#userStatus').val() == 'User' ? true : false;
 }
```

Comment: but you are using logged_in inside <script> tag

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean... What does this have to do with what I'm trying? (Sorry for bad english, I'm Spanish...)

Comment: your `logged_in` function is executing inside `JavaScript`. Then no need to use quotes.

Comment: Oh, I have forget in the jsfiddle, but not in my page.

Comment: I don't know why in my web doesn't work... I will edit somethings.. ;)

Comment: I think no need to echo in php with javascript. you can use directly as <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

Comment: I have PHP variables... ¬¬

Comment: Well I have fix it... I have declared the <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script> after that code :/

Comment: @Ikillnukes if you've fixed it you need to follow `SO` rules to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I fix the code, not him... Elektro tio... No se a que viene todo, solo te he dicho que el Regex era correcto y ya te has enfadao, no quería insinuar nada, y si perdona por cogerte el code... Pero no se a que viene ahora a intentar hundirme nada, por 2 cosas que he dicho, vamos a hablar las cosas, por favor, no me seas crío...